# static_cast throws error but C-style cast works

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

When I use `static_cast`:

```
const C* cObj; // C is a user-defined class
void* obj = static_cast<void*>(cObj);
```

I get the error:

> Conversion loses qualifiers

But when I use C-style cast, it works:

```
const C* cObj;
void* obj = (void*)cObj;
```

Why is it so?

What is the correct way to do it via C++ style casts?

Comment: You're doing it wrong, you should cast to `const void*` (and of course `obj` should be of that type as well). You can't cast away `const` with `static_cast`.

Comment: A C-style cast is like a sledge-hammer; if it can it will and the programmer needs to be aware of the consequences.  If you are unsure then never use either C-style casts or `reintepret_cast` until you have read up on them, a starting point is: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What if I really want to remove `const`ness? Should I go for `const_cast<>` instead?

Comment: I'm not saying it's a good idea (it usually isn't) but yes that's the only way to cast away `const`. You might need two casts though, one for the `const` and the other for the type.

Comment: With that said, what is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Why are you doing this? Asking for help for a solution without telling us what it is supposed to solve is called [the *XY problem*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps if you ask about the *actual* problem we can help you solve it without casting away the `const`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is it so?

C-style cast works because has the power of multiple C++ casts combined. For example, it can cast away const-ness and reinterpret the pointer type at the same time. The process used by C++ compilers to decide how to interpret a particular C cast is described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).

A C++ way to cast a constant pointer is to cast it to another constant pointer, like this:

```
const void* obj = static_cast<const void*>(cObj);
```

If you also need to cast away const-ness, you can chain casts like this:

```
void* obj = const_cast<void*>(static_cast<const void*>(cObj));
```

Regular precautions of `const_cast` apply as usual: if the pointer that you are casting is pointing to a constant object, modifying that object through a non-const pointer after the cast causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If the path to ruin is really your intent...

```
struct C;

template<class T>
T* daringly_remove_const_and_damn_the_consequences(T const* p)
{
    return const_cast<T*>(p);
}

const C* cObj; // C is a user-defined class
void* obj = static_cast<void*>(daringly_remove_const_and_damn_the_consequences(cObj));
```